# RxJava vs RxGo performance difference

Tags: performance, rx-java, reactive-programming

Are there any performance differences between all ReactiveX implementations ? Is there a better ecosystem than an other for reactive programming ?

Comment: This question is very broad and not be answered in detail without further restrictions. RxJava is a very mature implementation and runs on the JVM. The JVM uses JIT compilation, RxGo runs on the Go runtime, which is ahead-of-time compiled. Do you have memory or cpu-resource-restrictions? Which HW should be used for performance? Which use-cases should be compared? The Reactive Framework provides the means to build reactive systems. If you were to benchmark a HTTP client with 10k requests, you would probably benchmark the runtime aswell. Summary: not that easy to answer.

Answer (score 0):

One is not "better" than the other:

- [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava), it its [version 3](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What%27s-different-in-3.0), is based on Java 8 (before it was limited to Java 6 API due to how Android was lagging behind in its runtime support)
  So if your ecosystem is Java or Android-base, you should consider RxJava
- [RxGo](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxGo) is based on Go: its philosophy is to implement the ReactiveX concepts and leverage the main Go primitives (channels, goroutines, etc.) so that the integration between the two worlds is as smooth as possible.
  If your program is in Go (like [those programs](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/ReactiveX/RxGo?tab=importedby)), you can use this library.
  For example: [`ganeshrvel/one-archiver`](https://github.com/ganeshrvel/one-archiver): All-in-one archiver package for Go.

Each one will have their benchmark challenges:

- RxJava: [3.x: parallel performs poorly with 10+ parallelism](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/6931)
- RxGo: [limited benchmark scenario](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxGo/search?q=benchmark&type=code) (I have only found one).